# What is the difference between "Drop in" and "pop in"

Tags: verbs

In British English do "drop in to see someone" and "pop in to see someone" have different meanings?

Comment: "Drop in" has the notion of an unexpected visit, while "pop in" has the notion of a short visit.

Comment: They mean the same but I think it's usually _drop by or pop in_ although it could equally be the other way round, both could be organised beforehand or could be spontaneous. _I'll drop by/pop in to see you tonight_ vs _I've just dropped by/popped in to see you_.

Comment: Agree with Jim, the only **real difference** is that "pop" is shorter-feeling.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to agree with Ashley. Also 'pop in' seems to me more purposeful - 'I'll pop in with that garden rake I borrowed from you, in the morning'.

'Drop-in' strikes me as something you do when you are out for a drive. You realise you are near Harry's house, so you 'drop in' and see him; when hopefully he will make you a cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are quite similar although I would personally use them to indicate different lengths of time, to pop in would mean just a quick visit, whilst drop in would mean a little longer

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both other answers and find it related back to causation and tone. The definitions of each word support Ashley & WS2's intuition:

> pop:
> 3. To move quickly or unexpectedly; appear abruptly
>
> drop:
> 4. To cause to fall
>
> (Definitions via [freedirectionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/))

It seems like popping in has explosive intention behind it, while to drop in feels more calm and without implied intent. Both have elements of surprise. In my usage, I would ***pop in* to my coworker's office** but I may ***drop in* (possibly late?) to a party**.